# How to install ClickOnce application without a local manifest

Tags: installation, clickonce, manifest

I have a ClickOnce application sitting on my company's file server, including the setup.exe and the .application manifest. Due to network settings, users that wish to install my application must copy the setup.exe to their local machine. Unfortunately, the installation fails if it can't find the manifest. We can get around this by copying the manifest to the local machine alongside the setup.exe. The manifest has the "deployment location" set as the file server, so the copied local manifest is never used; it's only purpose is to placate the installer.

Is there a way to tell the installer to look for the application manifest at the specific file server location, and not look for it in the same folder as the setup.exe?